# Add trigger in onEdit() event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am wanting to run a process overnight if data on a specific sheet is updated. I cunningly thought of installing a trigger for that night if the criteria match. I don't want to run the trigger every night regardless and look for a 'changed' attribute stored somewhere because a new file is created every year and the ending of the overnight processing is somewhat flexible... so if no data was updated, don't even check.

I have this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    var range = e.range;
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    var sheet_name = sheet.getName();
    Logger.log("Edit on sheet '" + sheet_name +"'");
    if(sheet_name == C_SHEET_FORECAST) {
      installOvernightTrigger();
    }
  } catch(x) {
    Logger.log(x);
  } finally {
    endLog();
  }
}
```

What I get in the log is `Exception: You do not have permission to call newTrigger`.

I appreciate that without careful handling this could climb up itself and possibly melt google, but is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple triggers (such as naming a function onEdit) [cannot do anything that requires authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions), which includes creating other triggers.

Rename `onEdit` to something else and [create an installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) for it.